# I'm trying to load a popup from javascript, which works, however, when I click to close the popup it nothing happens

Tags: javascript, html

I've wrote the below code to load a popup when a page loads, however, when I click 'Continue' to close the popup - nothing happens. The button indents but the popup stays put. I was wondering if anybody had any ideas?

```
<p>This is the normal text that would be on the page anyway.</p>

<p>There's an awful lot of this text on a normal page with lots of graphics and stuff as well.</p>


<div id="reminderPopup">
    <div class="popupBackground">
        <div class="popupInner">
            <h2>Remember, if you have opened and resolved a complaint on this call to close the ADR.</h2>
            <p><!--additional text here--></p>
            <button id="close" onclick="closeReminderPopup()">Continue</button>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function pageLoadCompleteEvent(){
    document.getElementById("reminderPopup").style.display="block";
};
function closeReminderPopup(){
    document.getElementById("reminderPopup").style.display="none";
};  
</script>
```

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Comment: EDIT: I had to format the code to be accepted in here - now it does not load the popup at all...

Comment: When does the pageLoadCompleteEvent() gets called?

Comment: `<html>` must only contain `<head>` and `<body>`. Just put your `<script>` at the end of `<body>`, but inside it.

Comment: Page load event is called <body onload=pageLoadCompleteEvent()">   And putting it in the <body> didn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow :). Are there any errors in your JavaScript console? (Press F12, then go to "console"). If no, are there error after you clicked the button and nothing happened? Your code seems fine.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://next.plnkr.co/edit/Owd1WQB7QM5acUnV96Zw?p=preview&preview

Comment: Hey CodeF0x - HTTO403: Forbidden - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfil it. Maybe it's my work server stopping it?

Comment: Also error - SCRIPT5009: SCRIPT5009: 'closeReminderPopup' is not defined

Comment: How are you getting a 403? The second error is pretty straight forward, the function `closeReminderPopup` can't be found. (Maybe a typo, or a problem with timing). Can you provide more detail? Are you requesting something that explains the HTTP error message? What's your development environment? Just a  simple page on maybe localhost or just the file opened in the browser? Or a live delopment server of some kind?

Comment: Looks like it's the system we use that is stopping this. Thanks though, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. Try running it in the code snippet tool:

```js
 function pageLoadCompleteEvent(){
  document.getElementById("reminderPopup").style.display="block";
 };
 function closeReminderPopup(){
  document.getElementById("reminderPopup").style.display="none";
 };
```

```html
<html>
<body>
 <p>This is the normal text that would be on the page anyway.</p>
 
 <p>There's an awful lot of this text on a normal page with lots of graphics and stuff as well.</p>
 

 <div id="reminderPopup">
  <div class="popupBackground">
   <div class="popupInner">
    <h2>Remember, if you have opened and resolved a complaint on this call to close the ADR.</h2>
    <p><!--additional text here--></p>
    <button id="close" onclick="closeReminderPopup()">Continue</button>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```